# How to deal with Cookie Consent (GDPR) in Magento 2

Tags: cookie, gdpr, cookie-domain, allow-cookie

I am trying to implement a Cookie Consent feature in Magento 2.
I would like to show to the customers a pop-up, where I have the cookies split in groups and the customer can choose what he want to allow or deny. All fine unit here.
My main question is : how can i manage the cookies. More precise how can i deny cookie on the technical way in magento and how can i make sure that the cookies that were denied are not created on the next page load?

I know that there are some extension available on the market like https://amasty.com/cookie-consent-for-magento-2.html but i want to implement my custom functionality.
I know that we can use default magento functions like the one from here : https://www.codextblog.com/code-snippet/how-to-create-read-update-and-delete-custom-cookie-in-magento-2/ but it will be not optimal at all to check all the cookies at every page load and add or delete them..

Another approach will be by somehow to check the header and check what we have in the set-cookies param but i am not sure how to do that.

I am asking this because for sure there is something already made and I don't want to invent the wheel, but I am just wandering how is the best approach for this question.
Thanks in advanced!